# While loop skipping Cin

Tags: c++, c++11

```
while (guess<1234 or guess>9876)
  {
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    cin >> guess;
  }
```

The output spams 'invalid,' giving me not time to enter a new guess. How can I get it to pause?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter for numeric values (see [How can I get std::cin to skip invalid input characters?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html) ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int guess;
    while (guess<1234 or guess>9876) {
        cout << "Invalid" << guess << endl;
        cin >> guess;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: `guess` is uninitialized... you must do `cin >> guess` before check `guess<1234 or guess>9876`.

Comment: I only looked at the "spamming", assuming that guess would be initialized somewhere before.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cin` seems to be in a bad state due to trying to read in "bad" data before, like trying to read "hello" into an `int`. You should clear it if it's in an bad state:

```
while (guess<1234 or guess>9876)
{
    cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    if (!cin) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    cin >> guess;
}
```

you'll also need to include `<limits>` for `std::numeric_limits`.

Comment: `guess` is uninitialized...

Comment: @ikh where? In mdsl's answer it is. But in OP's question and my answer you can only see the while loop that is relevant. `guess` is supposed to be initialized before it, in the part of the code you can't see. Initializing it inside the loop wouldn't make sense.